# my php curl script works i now need to send users:pass in array

Tags: php, ajax, arrays, curl

okay so here we go here is my curl script

```
<?php
// Function file
include('func.php');

//Data for Check function

$user = "username goes here";
$password = "password goes here";

//Data for boundary values

$upper_boundary = "999.99";
$lower_boundary = "0.00";

//Login script 

checkcpu($user, $password);

//Check  script

$html = check('https://example/home.aspx');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$value = $xpath->query('//label[@id="ctl00_ctl00_PageContainer_MyAccountCpuContainer_symPercent"]/following-sibling::text()')->item(0)->nodeValue;



//Checking for value and echo results

if (($value >= $lower_boundary) && ($value <= $upper_boundary)) {
$result_string = "Checked ". $user .  " : " . $password . " cpu cooling rat:";                
echo "Live - $result_string $value"; 
//Erase Cookie Content
signout();
}else{ 
checkcpu($user, $password);

//Check  script

$html = check('https://example/home.aspx');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$value = $xpath->query('//label[@id="ctl00_ctl00_PageContainer_MyAccountCpuContainer_symPercent"]/following-sibling::text()')->item(0)->nodeValue;

if (($value >= $lower_boundary) && ($value <= $upper_boundary)) {
$result_string = "Checked ". $user .  " : " . $password . " cpu cool rate:";                
echo "Live - $result_string $value"; 
//Erase Cookie Content
signout();
}else{ 
echo "Die - $user $password $value"; 
}
}


?>
```

i want to send an array of data wich i copy and paste into a text box like this

```
user:pass
user:pass
user:pass
user:pass
user:pass
user:pass
user:pass
user:pass
user:pass
user:pass
```

i want this array to be sent using ajax to my php file so that the user goes into username goes her on my curl script and the password to go in password goes here then echo my results in an array 1 by 1

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: i need to send data in array to my curl script using ajax as i stated in my post

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that.

Comment: marc b is there any way you know how i can send users in array

Comment: @AshleyGraham - you're likely to get more help if you can show that you've tried to do this yourself.

Comment: @andrewsi this is the problem i am just trying to understnad java code if i can be ponted to a way someone has sent user:pass and split int up to send it to my php through ajax i would be greatfull

Answer (score 0):

Your post doesn't say whether or not you are using jQuery but I highly recommend it. With it you can do something like this:

**HTML FILE**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="userpass">
    <textarea name="userpass"></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<script>
    (function($) {
        $('#userpass').submit(function() {
            $.post('yourscript.php', $(this).serialize())
             .done(function(response){
                 // Do something with the response if you want.
             })
        ));
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

**yourscript.php**

```
<?php
    // Parse the user:pass string
    preg_match_all('|(.*):(.*)|', $_POST['userpass'], $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        // loop through all of the matches and do something with the username/password
        list(, $username, $password) = $match;

        echo $username . ' - ' . $password . "\n";
    }
```